# How to convert a BitmapImage in a MemoryStream on a Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, memorystream, bitmapimage

Hej gutter,

I need to save a BitmapImage to a MemoryStream to then be able to get it as a byte array. I've found some solutions over the internet but none of them is for Windows Store apps, so when I tried to use them, I was always missing some classes not available for Windows Store apps.

Any help?

Comment: Both [WinRTXamlToolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/) and [WriteableBitmapExtensions](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) make it pretty easy to get the byte array.

Comment: You can't create a byte array directly from the BitmapImage. You need access to the source of the BitmapImage. Depending on how it was created, it may be in UriSource.